# Why maven-surefire-plugin skip tests with log message "because it has already been run for this configuration"?

Tags: java, maven, mule, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin

I can't understand why maven-surefire-plugin doesn't run jUnit4 test. My pom is (can't add it here because "it looks post is mostly code"): http://pastebin.com/Jj3iJZpY

When I execute `mvn clean test` cmd window shows:

```
C:\Users\maya\git\services>mvn clean test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building services 1.0.18
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ services ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\maya\git\services\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-mule-plugin:1.9:attach-test-resources (default-attach-test-resources) @ services ---
[INFO] attaching test resource C:\Users\maya\git\services\src\main\app
[INFO]
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:add-resource (add-resource) @ services ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ services ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-mule-plugin:1.9:filter-resources (default-filter-resources) @ services ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ services ---
[INFO] Compiling 60 source files to C:\Users\maya\git\services\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:testResources (default-testResources) @ services ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ services ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\maya\git\services\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test (default-test) @ services ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test (default) @ services ---
[INFO] Skipping execution of surefire because it has already been run for this configuration
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.554 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-11T15:48:05+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 48M/312M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Test class is:

```
  package com.comp.utils.UtilsTest;

    import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.junit.Test;



    public class UtilsTest {
         private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(UtilsTest.class.getName());


        @Test
        public void testHasPersonSameProd() {


             boolean hasSameProduct = false;

            assertTrue("Should be True", hasSameProduct);
        }
    }
```

Why maven-surefire-plugin:2.19 runs twice and doesn't want to run my test class? How to run test in my case? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the pom you linked (which should be included into the question actually, as the link may be broken in the future):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <executions>
            <execution>
                    <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
            </execution>
    </executions>


    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <configuration>
            <includes>
                    <include>UtilTest.java</include>
            </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

- The Maven Surefire Plugin runs twice because you configured an additional execution of the plugin, without providing an `id` element and as such by default it is called `default` (`maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test (default)`). This execution runs after the out-of-the-box Maven configuration for Surefire (`maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test (default-test)`). So, as a consequence, you have two executions (`default` and `default-test`). Removing the `executions` section on the Surefire plugin configuration you would only have one execution (the `default-test`).
- You also have a typo in the Surefire configuration, the `<include>UtilTest.java</include>` configuration points to the `UtilTest.java` class, while in your question it is named `UtilsTest` (note the additional 's').
- If the test class is under `src/test/java` folder, then you don't need to configure its inclusion, since it also already follow the default convention of Surefire, `"**/*Test.java"`.
- The message you are having (`Skipping execution of surefire because it has already been run for this configuration`) is because your `configuration` element for the Surefire plugin is outside any `executions` element, which means is applied to all plugin executions, even the default one (`default-test`).

So you could probably remove the whole Surefire plugin section from your pom and the issue should be fixed.

Comment: Thank you. The mistake was in `<include>UtilTest.java</include>`. Should be <include>UtilTest**s**.java</include>